# Binding enum with converter. Converter method is not invoked

Tags: wpf, enums, type-conversion

I have the following converter:

```
public class EnumDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{       

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {                        
            var enumValue = (MyEnum)value;

            //GetDescription is method to read attribute string value.
            return enumValue.GetDescription();            
    }        
}
```

I have a listbox:

```
<ListBoxItem Content=
"{Binding {x:Static Enums:MyEnum.Video}, Converter={StaticResource DescriptionConverter}}"/>
```

When I run this, I get exception "unable to cast MyEnum to string". Breakpoint inside converter is not triggered.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to bind the Enum to the Binding's `Path` property

Specify that the Enum is the `Source` property instead

```
<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding
    Source={x:Static Enums:MyEnum.Video}, 
    Converter={StaticResource DescriptionConverter}}"/>
```